# Regarding adjustment of the table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dropbox

Here i want to show disclosure indicator for the folder or directory:

[image]

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

DropboxCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Dropbox_Cell2"];

DBMetadata *metadata = [filesNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.btnIcon setTitle:metadata.path forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[cell.btnIcon addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDownloadPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


if (metadata.isDirectory) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.btnIcon.hidden = YES;
      NSLog(@"yes");
}else {
    NSLog(@"No");
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.btnIcon.hidden = NO;
}


NSString *sectionTitle = [newsectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionRows = [dict objectForKey:sectionTitle];
NSString *cellName = [sectionRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//cell.lblTitle.text = metadata.filename;
 cell.lblTitle.text = cellName;
return cell;
}
```

Please refer the images and help.

Rest client delegate method which is used to load and manipulate data:
[image: Rest client delegate method which is used to load and manipulate data]

`numberOfRowsInSection` method of table view:
[image: numberOfRowsInSection method of table view]

Comment: whats the question/problem?

Comment: Will you please explain your problem a bit more as its not clear from your question.

Comment: @CW0007007  i want to show disclosure indicator for the folder or directory presented in the metadata of dropbox. I am not able to get it in tableview delegate methods.

Comment: @VishalSonawane from the dropbox i am fetching files and folders and displaying in tableview in alphabetical order. But problem came into the picture while displaying the folder structure. i want to show disclosure indicator for the table view cell which contains directory (folder). this directory object is coming from the dropbox rest client load metadata function.

Comment: Have you tried with breakpoints? Is your code flow correct? I mean if your condition metadata.isDirectory satisfies at any point?

Comment: @VishalSonawane see i have added screenshot for dropbox delegate method. where "marrDownloadData" is initialised.

Comment: @VishalSonawane yes i checked metadata.isDirectory in rest client loadData method it is giving me true when there is Folder 1 is in loop.

Comment: Try to set disclosure type from storyboard .

Comment: can add code of cellForRow method ?

Comment: @Hosny website is not allowing me to add one more image because of reputation limit

Comment: ok , please edit your question and add it .

Comment: @Hosny i have added code in the question.

Comment: @VishalSonawane if i set it from storyboard will it work for dropbox data? indicator will be displayed for all the files. I just want that indicator for folders or directories.

Comment: I think that problem in using sections so you need in cellForRow method to specify any section with  any row  .

Comment: @Hosny right exactly.  i'm getting (metadata.isDirectory) false.

Comment: That I expect it , because indexPath.row change upon section because you return more than one section , try to resolve this good luck .

Comment: @Hosny yea thanks a lot.

Comment: @aditya check my answer and if it helped you please up vote and accept it to help the others , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you return more than one section , so `indexPath.row` in `cellForRow` method change depend on section so try to handle `metadata.isDirectory` depend on section and row not row only , I hope that help you .